# Linq to XML, multiple (sub-element) where and group clauses

Tags: linq-to-xml

Being fairly new to Linq, I've spent far too many hours on this, so it's time to ask the experts for some pointers :)

In summary, I'd like to filter the input using two where and a group by clause, creating output which I can throw into a

```
new <SMO<SMO<Plane>>(id, items)
```

type collection. (SMO is my own ObservableCollection implementation instantiated by giving a Title and a 'root' XElements.)

My XML input is similar to this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
  <id>manifest id</id>
  <locale>US</locale>
  <plane>
    <id>First</id>
    <definition>
      <description>plane description</description>
      <type>plane type</type>
      <item>
        <name>Item 1</name>
        <condition>item condition</condition>
        <description>item description</description>
        <ondelivery>
          <c>instant</c>
          <p1>delivery parameter 1</p1>
          <p2>delivery parameter 2</p2>
        </ondelivery>
      </item>
      <item>
        <name>Item 2</name>
        <condition>item condition</condition>
        <description>item description</description>
        <ondelivery>
          <c>email</c>
          <p1>delivery parameter 1</p1>
        </ondelivery>
      </item>
    </definition>
  </plane>
  <plane>
    <id>Second</id>
    <definition>
      <description>plane description</description>
      <type>plane type</type>
      <item>
        <name>Item 1</name>
        <condition>item condition</condition>
        <description>item description</description>
        <ondelivery>
          <c>instant</c>
          <p1>delivery parameter 1</p1>
          <p2>delivery parameter 2</p2>
        </ondelivery>
      </item>
      <item>
        <name>Item 2</name>
        <condition>item condition</condition>
        <description>item description</description>
        <ondelivery>
          <c>email</c>
          <p1>delivery parameter 1</p1>
        </ondelivery>
      </item>
      <item>
        <name>Item 3</name>
        <condition>item condition</condition>
        <description>item description</description>
        <ondelivery>
          <c>instant</c>
          <p1>delivery parameter 1</p1>
          <p2>delivery parameter 1</p2>
          <p3>delivery parameter 1</p3>
        </ondelivery>
      </item>
    </definition>
  </plane>
</manifest>
```

Basically, each *plane* has a single *definition* containing any number of *item*'s. Each *item* contains a single *c* followed by any number of *p*N's.

What I need to do is filter out a single *plane* based on it's *id*. This is trivial enough by running something like;

```
    var oput = (from c in doc.Element("manifest").Elements("plane")
        where (string)c.Element("id") == "Second"
        select c);
```

The problem arises when I have to further filter this based on each *item*'s *c* property (but at the same time have a complete *plane* element to work with). For example, from the source above I need to pull all *item*'s where *c* equals "instant" from *plane* "second".

From this I want/need output similar to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
  <id>manifest id</id>
  <locale>US</locale>
  <plane>
    <id>Second</id>
    <definition>
      <description>plane description</description>
      <type>plane type</type>
      <item>
        <name>Item 1</name>
        <condition>item condition</condition>
        <description>item description</description>
        <ondelivery>
          <c>instant</c>
          <p1>delivery parameter 1</p1>
          <p2>delivery parameter 2</p2>
        </ondelivery>
      </item>
      <item>
        <name>Item 3</name>
        <condition>item condition</condition>
        <description>item description</description>
        <ondelivery>
          <c>instant</c>
          <p1>delivery parameter 1</p1>
          <p2>delivery parameter 1</p2>
          <p3>delivery parameter 1</p3>
        </ondelivery>
      </item>
    </definition>
  </plane>
</manifest>
```

in the form of an XElement (as I'm creating a *new Plane* class which takes this as input).

The best I've come up with so far is

```
    var oput = (from c in doc.Element("manifest").Elements("plane")
        where (string)c.Element("id") == "Second"
        from d.Elements("definition").Elements("item").Elements("c")
        where (string)d.Element("c") == "instant"
        select d);
```

which does filter correctly, but the output it gives me is, understandably, an IEnumerable of *ondelivery*'s.

I've tried playing around with the actual select by using c, d.Parent, new XElement("plane", d.Parent.Parent.Parent.Element("id"), d.Parent)) and so on, but I'm completely unable to get the sort of output I'm after.

As a bonus I'd like to group these at the same time, based upon the *plane* *id*. I have grasped the group by clause, but not how to format the output it gives. Ideally I'll need it output as a (String, IEnumerable) like ("Second", (XElement(Item 1), XElement(Item 2))) whereas I always seem to end up with an (IEnumerable(String, IEnumerable)) where the outer IEnumerable has an item count of 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use your original query which selects `plane` elements and then add some code to remove the unwanted `item` elements like this:

```
var oput = (from c in doc.Descendants("plane")
            where (string)c.Element("id") == "Second"
            select c);

foreach (var plane in oput)
{
    foreach (var item in plane.Descendants("item").Where((x) => x.Descendants("c").First().Value != "instant").ToList() )
    {
        item.Remove();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(plane); // or whatever you need to do with each plane.
}
```

The call to `ToList()` for the items loop is critical because without it, the `foreach` will break when one of the items is removed. Essentially calling `ToList()` makes a copy of the list to itterate over that isn't modified by the `Remove` method.